# Plot complex numbers in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, complex-numbers

Is there a way to plot complex number in an elegant way with `ggplot2`? 
`plot {graphics}` does it for my `snowflake` vector of values, but I would prefer to have it in `ggplot2`. The `ggplot2` tutorials I came across do not mention a *complex* word.

```
snowflake <- c(complex(real=0, imaginary=0),
               complex(real=1/3, imaginary=0),
               complex(real=1/2, imaginary=(3^(1/2))/6),
               complex(real=2/3, imaginary=0),
               complex(real=1, imaginary=0))
plot(snowflake, type="l")
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, It appears the suggestion below does not work with my more complex figures - `plot {graphics}` lines the points in the order given by the vector of values, whereas `qplot` **does not**. Se the example below:

```
my.snowflake <- c( 0.0000000+0.0000000i, 0.1111111+0.0000000i,
                   0.1666667+0.0962250i, 0.2222222+0.0000000i,
                   0.3333333+0.0000000i, 0.3888889+0.0962250i,
                   0.3333333+0.1924501i, 0.4444444+0.1924501i,
                   0.5000000+0.2886751i, 0.5555556+0.1924501i,
                   0.6666667+0.1924501i, 0.6111111+0.0962250i,
                   0.6666667+0.0000000i, 0.7777778+0.0000000i,
                   0.8333333+0.0962250i, 0.8888889+0.0000000i,
                   1.0000000+0.0000000i)
```

Results:

```
plot(my.snowflake, type = "l")
```

[image]

```
qplot(Re(my.snowflake), Im(my.snowflake), geom="line")
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just extract the real and imaginary parts of the number with `Re` and `Im`, then pass them to ggplot2 as x and y:

```
qplot(Re(snowflake), Im(snowflake), geom="path")
```

[image: The OP's plot in ggplot2]

In your update, you pointed out that `geom_line` doesn't work for a nontrivial case, so you'll want to use `geom_path` instead, which connects the points in the order they're provided. Here's your more complex example with `geom_path`:

[image: The OP's updated plot in ggplot2, with geom_path]

Comment: Peyton, thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, it does not work well with my more complicated examples - please see the post update.

Comment: You're right, it looks like `geom_line` isn't a good substitute. I've updated my example to use `geom_path`, as baptiste suggested in the comments. `geom_path` will connect the points in the order you provide them.